# Getting input from user without using "input" function

Tags: python, input, user-input

Is there a way to get input from the user in python without using the function "input"?

Need to be compatible to python 2.7 and 3.7

Comment: Not written there but you can also use directly [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

Comment: "Input from the user" could mean a lot of things.  Record gestures from the camera? Voice input via microphone? Scan a document? Move the mouse? This question can hardly be answered.

Comment: I'd agree with tomerikoo's suggestion, banning `input` and reading directly from `sys.stdin` is probably the most straightforward way to handle this, though slightly less convenient.